# Need to input a vector of variables into a function and for it to use all the unique combinations

Tags: r

I have a function with 2 inputs and a dataframe

I have a vector of variables 3, 8 ,9

I want to run the function on every combination of variables. For this example, it doesn't matter which way round the numbers are so for example 3 and 8 is the same as 8 and 3

so there are 3 unique combinations: 3 and 8, 3 and 9, 8 and 9

I can do this in a verbose way as demonstrated below:

```
add_up <- function(x,y,df){
nrow(df)+x+y  
}

add_up(x=3, y=8, df=iris)
add_up(x=3, y=9, df=iris)
add_up(x=9, y=9, df=iris)
```

I want to somehow modify the function so that it accepts the vector of variables, works out the unique combinations and then iterates through them.

Can anyone suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to accept a single vector (instead of both `x` and `y`), and use it with `combn`.

```r
add_up <- function(x, y = NULL, df) {
  if (is.null(y)) {
    y <- x[2]
    x <- x[1]
  }
  nrow(df) + x + y
}
combn(c(3, 8, 9), 2, FUN = add_up, df = iris)
# [1] 161 162 167
```

The only reason I kept `y=NULL` in there is if `add_up` is used in other places where having explicit `x` and `y` are needed; if the function is to be used solely in this context, it would be simpler to define the formals as `function(x, df)` (in this case).

The easiest way to see how this is being used is to use the default `FUN=c` in combn:

```r
combn(c(3, 8, 9), 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    8
# [2,]    8    9    9
```

where the different combinations are in each column.